How to Add Mint a supply to a token and open the mint to everyone and not only my wallet with the mint Authority
I followed the link here to create a fungible spl-token: < https://www.soldev.app/course/token-program> .
I have the following questions though:

How do I specify a mint cap so no more than the specified amount can be minted to the supply?. For example: specifying a mint cap of 1,000,000 and not more than 1,000,000 tokens are minted.

How to open the mint so anyone can mint an amount we specify and now more?. For example every individual can mint only 500 tokens.

How to close the mint after a specific time? For example: Close minting after 3:00 PM

Do i just mint 1,000,000 tokens to my mint Authority address and create a token pool on raydium & orca and let people buy / sell the token and this fixes ever issue?


Please and Thank you as you take your time to help.

If you want to programmatically control how your token is minted, and allow anyone to do it, your best bet is to develop your own on-chain program.

You can specify the limit in your on-chain program by checking that the supply will not go over 1,000,000.
Your program will only allow an instruction to mint 500.
Your program can look at the on-chain Clock and disallow minting after a certain time.
I'm not sure I understand how that solves your problem.

